# How to derive a contract body from a serialized static object?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-contract, openapi-generator

Let me preface this by saying that I come from a dotnet background and am not overly familiar with Java.  I'm attempting to minimize the need to update contract/DTO objects for consumers, by sharing objects that would be used as schema for a controller.  For an example, generating a schema using openAPI:

```
mysample.yml
openapi: "3.0.2"
paths:
  /mySampleEndpoint:
    post:
      operationId: sample
      requestBody: 
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "https://remote.definition.for.sampleendpoint.request.definition.yml#components/schemas/SampleEndpointDefinition"
#response removed for brevity
```

This works splendidly so far, but it becomes a little more difficult when I want to write contract tests.    I would expect my consumers to be generating their requests by serializing an instance of this shared object, and rather than handwriting the json objects for the body, I want to write the request objects by serializing a static final instance of the request object.

The current way to generate a contract test is either via a .yml or .groovy file, I'll use the groovy format since I think it has more promise in this case.

```
ContractCheckV1.groovy (as documented)
[
  Contract.make{
    request {
      method: 'POST'
      urlPath ('api/v1/mySampleEndpoint')
      headers: {
        header('Content-Type': 'application/json')
      }
      body( """
        {
          "foo": 1,
          "bar": "value",
          "baz": false 
        }
   """)
    }
    response {
      status 200
    }
  }
]
```

It's pretty easy to see that the request body can get cumbersome if we end up with sufficiently complex objects, so what I'd rather do is something like this.  Apologies, I'll be using C# syntax because it's more concise.

```
myTestDate.csJava //why am I doing this?

public static class myTestData () {  

  public static SampleEndpointDefinition testObject (){
    return new SampleEndpointDefinition{
      foo = 1,
      bar = "value",
      baz = false
    };
  }
}
```

And we would expect to use it in the .groovy file like so:

```
ContractCheckV1.groovy //as desired
SampleEndpointDefinition successObject = myTestData.testObject();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
string successObjectJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(successObject);

[
  Contract.make{
    request {
      method: 'POST'
      urlPath ('api/v1/mySampleEndpoint')
      headers: {
        header('Content-Type': 'application/json')
      }
      body( successObjectJson )
    }
    response {
      status 200
    }
  }
]
```

It seems that there's a compilation order issue with trying to pull in the package for myTestData or SampleObjectDefinition because of the way that the generated code interacts with this.  I'm not sure how to progress.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If your object had a static map that it would return (as a json body) then you don't have to serialize it to a json. It's enough for you to pass that map to the contract.

If however you can't use a map and it must be a structure then you can use groovy JsonOutput http://groovy-lang.org/json.html#_jsonoutput instead of object mapper that you would need on the classpath.

Also remember that this class of yours needs to be present on the classpath both on the consuner and producer side. Example is present here (jar with common code is here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/common and then you can check how producer and consumer are setup to reference that code.

Comment: Part of the issue is that the class for SampleEndpointDefinition is generated by openapiGenerator.  The signature is defined in a remote .yml file, and builds to a java file, which doesn't seem to be able to import to the contracts.groovy because it's not packaged into a JAR, and instead is a sibling in the project. Because the yml origin is remote, it's trivial to distribute between producer and consumer. Apologies if my nomenclature is off, I'm not used to javaland.